# Trying to print number using for loop in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I have trying to print the following number using for loop in C#

```
a 100 b 100
a 101 b 101
a 102 b 102
a 103 b 103
a 104 b 104
a 105 b 105
```

I have tried this code to get output:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i > 200; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j>200;j++)
            {
                if ((i % 0) == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following output:

```
0
10
20
30
.
.
..
200
```

Is there any solution

Comment: If you are expecting the output to start from 100, why are you having the loop start from 0?

Comment: why are you using mod to print out a line that seemingly just increments a value by one?

Comment: you aren't using anything from your inner loop.  Have you stepped through this?

Comment: And how do you get that output? `i % 0` can never be `1`. I'm actually suprised that `i % 0` does not raise a `DivisionByZeroException`. Ah no, `j > 200` is never true so it is never executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
static void Main()
{
    for (int i = 100; i <= 105; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("a " + i.ToString() + " b " + i.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for(int  i = 100; i <= 105; i++){
    Console.WriteLine($"a {i} b {i}");
}
```

EDIT: Note, this type of string interpolation was introduced with C#6

Comment: that works with c# 6

Comment: @DanielA.White you are right. This method of string interpolation is new with C# 6

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
for(int  i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("a {0} b {0}"), 100+i);
}
```